# VMware Player VM - 1 core CPU limitation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-player

I'm using a VM with VMware Player to write code and compile.
As my current program is huge, the compilation takes a while to be done (upto 5 minutes)
using 25% of my 4 cores CPU on my host = 100% of one core.

It seems that the VM is limited to use 1 single core.

Is there a way to optimize the number of cores a VM can use? 
I'd like to use 50% or 75% of my 4 cores CPU.

Thanks

Comment: Is the image configured to use more than 1 cpu?

Comment: If I use more than 1 cpu in the VM, it will not use more than 1 core on the host.

Comment: What is the value if you look at the Hardware tab and Processors under Player > Manage > Virtual Machine Settings?

Comment: it shows the value "1"

Comment: I entered "2" now and when I compile, it still uses 25% of the 4-core processor. Certainly because the compilation is a single process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're limited by the number of parallel build tasks you can run, not the VM CPU configuration, e.g., by default, `make` will run [a single step at a time](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html). Try running several steps in parallel, e.g., run [`make -j4`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html) or equivalent for your build system.

On a separate note, a VM may be more overhead for you than you might like; consider using [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) to host your development environment.