# Parallel build/compilation task for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, build, parallel-processing

compiling my project in my Virtual Machine takes a huge amount of time and only use 25% of my processor (1 core out of 4) because the build process does not use **parallel** build tasks.

Is it possible under Delphi 7 to have parallel build tasks?

Have a look here for details :
[VMware Player VM - 1 core CPU limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809192/vmware-player-vm-1-core-cpu-limitation)

Thanks

Comment: Probably not relevant, but are your source files inside the VM or external and mapped into it using VMWare's Shared Folders or equivalent?  I found Shared Folders was hopelessly slow for compiling.

Comment: Not in Shared Folders.

Comment: How do you want to decompose the build process? Bear in mind that if unit A depends on unit B, that imposes an ordering constraint during compilation.

Comment: Hello, how can I decompose the build process to speed up the compilation/build ?

Answer (score 3):

If you call the compiler like `start dcc32.exe xxxx yyy` it starts asynchronously, so if you have 4 of those lines, you'll have 4 compilers running in parallel.

If the building process consists of compiling multiple items, you can create a batchfile to do the compiling.

If you only compile a single exe or library, you're pretty much stuch in a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

No version of Delphi (not even the latest version) supports multi-thread/multi-core parallel compiling at all.  As far as I know, there is no third party addon for it, either (unlike C++Builder, via TwineCompiler).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to compile **multiple projects**(!) in parallel, but this requires setting up your own build process.

There is no built-in solution or Add-On that I'm aware of <sup>1)</sup>, and without digging deeper into that stuff, I'd suspect one is lost simply because of the black box "compiler". That's something LLVM and Roslyn etc. are going to change, a still ongoing process.

One question is, how long does it take to become true mainstream. Another question is, how long it will take Emba to either open their black box, or at least implement such a feature into the compiler. Thinking about 64 bits, we will have to wait a few more years until they recognize that people usually have multiple cores in their CPUs these days.

And yet another question is, how big the market for Delphi 7-specific solutions really is today ...

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>That does not mean that there can't exist any. I just don't know it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you have a group of projects or a project group contains many projects.  Analyse the project dependencies (e.g.: requires clause in .dpk file) and build a dependencies relations structure, then build your projects by batches to utilize the CPU core.  It shall improve build speed dramatically depends on number of CPU cores you have.

Try https://github.com/ccy/msbuild.delphi.parallel